# Декодинг картинки

Tags: шифрование, стеганография

[image]

Как расшифровать изображение??????

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [Stegsolve](http://kmb.ufoctf.ru/stego/stegsolve/main.html). В красной битовой плоскости будет ваш флаг. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]